# Joint PDF using dummy variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X and Y are positive random variables whose joint PDF is given by
$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=4e^{-2(x+y)}$.

a) Find a PDF of X+Y

b) Find a joint PDF of $U=\frac{X}{Y}$  and V=X

c) Based on answer of (b), find a PDF of $U=\frac{X}{Y}$

Comment: Please help!! I really have no clue how to do joint PDF by using U and V!

Answer (score 0):

Edit : I've rewritten my entire answer.

Let $F_Y(y)$ denote the cdf of $Y$. Then $F_Y(y) = P(U/V \leq y) = P(U\leq yV, V > 0) + P(U\geq yV, V < 0)$

$F_Y(y) = \int_0^\infty \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{yv}f_U(u)du \right]f_V(v)dv +  \int_{-\infty}^0 \left[ \int_{yv}^{\infty}f_U(u)du \right]f_V(v)dv$
$ = \int_0^\infty \left[ F_U(yv) \right]f_V(v)dv +  \int_{-\infty}^0 \left[ 1 - F_U(xv) \right]f_V(v)dv$
$f_Y(y) = F_Y(y)^\prime = \int_0^\infty \left[ vf_U(yv) \right]f_V(v)dv +  \int_{-\infty}^0 \left[-vf_U(xv) \right]f_V(v)dv$
$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |v|f_U(yv)f_V(v)dv$

Comment: I know this particular part. I just don't know how to use it to solve (b) especially. How can I solve joint PDF of U and V?

Comment: Edited my original answer.

Comment: I am sorry T~T. It seems like I just cannot understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: I will edit my post and give you the full answer.

Comment: Sorry. I am just lost at this question. Thank you so much for helping me out

Comment: errr... are you still there?